# DRF ограничение данных во вложенной модели

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Я вывел все данные из models.py и пытаюсь сделать так, что бы при значение is_show = 0 эти данные не выводились в АПИ

Файл **models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book_number = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    short_desc = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    old_version = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)

class Price(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='book_id', blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False)
    price_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    is_discont = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_show = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)

class Store(models.Model):
    price = models.ForeignKey(Price, related_name='price_id' blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    store_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    store_location = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    is_show = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
```

файл **serializers.py**

```
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = [
            'store_name',
            'store_location',
            'is_show',
        ]
    
    
class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    store = StoreSerializer(
                           source='price_id',
                           many=True
                       )
    class Meta:
        model = Price
        fields = [
            'price',
            'price_date',
            'is_discont',
            'is_show',
            'store',
        ]


class ViewBookListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    price = PriceSerializer(
                           source='book_id',
                           many=True
                       )
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = [
            'book_number',
            'name',
            'language',
            'short_desc',
            'old_version',
            'created_by',
            'price',
        ]
```

Файл **views.py**

```
class BookFullList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ViewBookListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        data = Book.objects.filter(created_by=user, book_id__is_show=1, book_id__price_id__is_show=1)
        return data
```

**Результат ответа**

```
{
    'book_number': 231241,
    'name': 'Pt all test',
    'language': 'UA',
    'short_desc': 'this test',
    'old_version': 'test',
    'created_by': 1,
    'price': [
        {
            'book': 1, 
            'price': 231, 
            'price_date': 
            '2020-11-10', 
            'is_discont': 'True'
            'is_show': 1,
            'store':[{
                'price': 1, 
                'store_name': 535223, 
                'store_location': "Kyiv", 
                'is_show': 1
            },
            {
                'price': 1, 
                'store_name': 5353333, 
                'store_location': "Odessa", 
                'is_show': 0
            },
            {
                'price': 1, 
                'store_name': 535231, 
                'store_location': "Lviv", 
                'is_show': 1
            },
            ]
        },
        {
            'book': 231241, 
            'price': 111, 
            'price_date': '2020-11-10', 
            'is_discont': 'True'
            'is_show': 0
            'store':[{
                'price': 1, 
                'store_name': 535223, 
                'store_location': "Kyiv" 
            }
            ]
        },
        
    ]
}
```

А должен быть вот такой результат. Подскажите, что делаю не так ?

```
{
    'book_number': 231241,
    'name': 'Pt all test',
    'language': 'UA',
    'short_desc': 'this test',
    'old_version': 'test',
    'created_by': 1,
    'price': [
        {
            'book': 1, 
            'price': 231, 
            'price_date': 
            '2020-11-10', 
            'is_discont': 'True'
            'is_show': 1,
            'store':[{
                'price': 1, 
                'store_name': 535223, 
                'store_location': "Kyiv", 
                'is_show': 1
            },
            {
                'price': 1, 
                'store_name': 535231, 
                'store_location': "Lviv", 
                'is_show': 1
            },
            ]
        }, 
    ]
}
```

Comment: а так: book__price_is_show=1 ?

Comment: ```Price.objects.filter(created_by=user).exclude(is_show=0)```
Ваша модель не предусматривает связи с таблицей ```price```

Comment: Этот вариант не подходит получаю ошибку. 

`Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field book_number  on serializer ViewBookListSerializer.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the Price instance.
Original exception text was: Price object has no attribute book_number.`

Comment: Причина, по которой я выбрал такую реализацию модели в том, что сначала через веб приложении можно будет создать книгу и потом уже создавать цены и мазагины. при этом к каждой книге можно будет указать не одну цену и не один магазин